# How to filter using a toggle button in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display some data using an ngFor. I want to have a filter on the displayed data using a toggle.

I have so far made the filter to work partially so far. Currently when I click on the toggle it indeed filters my data. For example: When I click on the toggle "Gym" it returns all the houses which has an amenity gym. But it does not filter the houses when i click on say more than one toggle e.g when i click on "Gym" and "Wifi" It should return a list of houses with both the amenity: Gym and Wifi

I expect the filter to return a list of houses when I click on more than one toggle e.g when i click on "Gym" and "Wifi" It should return a list of houses with both the amenity: Gym and Wifi

My Component is:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Home } from '../../models/IHome.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './homes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homes.component.css']
})

export class HomesComponent implements OnInit {

  defaultSelection = 'All';
  searchText: any;
  address: string;
  counter = 0;
  homes: Home[];

  filterArgs: any = { type: '', address: '', car_type: '', amenity: '' };


  amenities = [
    {
      'name': 'Wifi',
      'value': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Gym',
      'value': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Swimming Pool',
      'value': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Garden',
      'value': false
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.homes = [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'type': 'Villa',
        'price': 920000,
        'address': 'CMC',
        'area': 6292,
        'bedrooms': 2,
        'bathrooms': 2,
        'car_type': 'Cars',
        'park_spots': 1,
        'amenity': ['Gym'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil10.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'type': 'Apartment',
        'price': 3000,
        'address': 'Summit',
        'area': 921,
        'bedrooms': 3,
        'bathrooms': 1,
        'car_type': 'Cars',
        'park_spots': 2,
        'amenity': ['Wifi'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil6.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'type': 'Villa',
        'price': 820000,
        'address': 'Hayat',
        'area': 4921,
        'bedrooms': 2,
        'bathrooms': 2,
        'car_type': 'Trucks',
        'park_spots': 3,
        'amenity': ['Garden', 'Swimming Pool'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil8.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'type': 'Apartment',
        'price': 420000,
        'address': 'Sarbet',
        'area': 3921,
        'bedrooms': 2,
        'bathrooms': 3,
        'car_type': 'Cars',
        'park_spots': 4,
        'amenity': ['Swimming Pool'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil1.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'type': 'Villa',
        'price': 629000,
        'address': 'Mekhanisa',
        'area': 2921,
        'bedrooms': 1,
        'bathrooms': 1,
        'car_type': 'Vans',
        'park_spots': 1,
        'amenity': ['Gym'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil6.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'type': 'Apartment',
        'price': 720000,
        'address': 'Bole',
        'area': 1921,
        'bedrooms': 3,
        'bathrooms': 3,
        'car_type': 'Bikes',
        'park_spots': 1,
        'amenity': ['Gym'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil5.jpg'
      }
    ];

  }

  amenityChange(item: any, e: any) {
    if (e.srcElement.checked === true) {
      console.log('checked');
      for (let i = 0; i < this.amenities.length; i++) {
        if (this.amenities[i].name === item) {
          this.amenities[i].value = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (e.srcElement.checked === false) {
      console.log('unchecked');
      this.counter = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.amenities.length; i++) {
        if (this.amenities[i].name === item) {
          this.amenities[i].value = false;
        }
      }
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < this.amenities.length; j++) {
      if (this.amenities[j].value === true) {
        this.filterArgs.amenity = this.amenities[j].name;
        this.counter = 1;
      }
    }
    if (this.counter === 0) {
      this.filterArgs.amenity = '';
    }
  }

}
```

My pipe is:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Home } from '../models/IHome.model';

@Pipe({
    name: 'amenitiesFilter',
    pure: false
})

export class AmenitiesFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(values: any[], filter: Home): any {
        /* console.log('amenities', values, filter); */
        if (!values || !filter || !filter.amenity) {
            return values;
        }
        return values.filter(item => {
            return item.amenity.indexOf(filter.amenity) !== -1;
        });
    }
}
```

My template is:

```html
 <p *ngFor="let amenity of amenities">
   <label>{{ amenity.name }}</label>
   <label class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" id={{amenity.name}} name="amenities" (change)="amenityChange(amenity.name, $event)">                      
     <span class="toggle round"></span>
   </label>
 </p>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let home of homes  | amenitiesFilter: filterArgs  
      | pricerangeFilter: 'price': min:max       
      | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 6, currentPage: p } ">

            <div class="homes" (click)="openDetails()">
                <img class="homes_content" src="{{ home.homeUrl }}" /><br>
                <div class="labels">
                    <label><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{{ home.address }}</label><br>
                    <label><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"
              aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{{ home.price | currency:"USD":"symbol" : "1.0"}}</label>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <button class="details"><i class="fa fa-tag fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{{ home.type }}</button>
                <label>&nbsp;SqFt:{{ home.area }}</label><br>
            </div>

   </ng-container>
   <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p= $event" style="float:right"></pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a bit your code.. don't use pipe

```
homes: Home[];
 homesFiltered:Home[];

  filterArgs: any = { type: '', address: '', car_type: '', amenity: '' };


  amenities = [
    {
      'name': 'Wifi',
      'value': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Gym',
      'value': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Swimming Pool',
      'value': false
    },
    {
      'name': 'Garden',
      'value': false
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.homes = [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'type': 'Villa',
        'price': 920000,
        'address': 'CMC',
        'area': 6292,
        'bedrooms': 2,
        'bathrooms': 2,
        'car_type': 'Cars',
        'park_spots': 1,
        'amenity': ['Gym'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil10.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'type': 'Apartment',
        'price': 3000,
        'address': 'Summit',
        'area': 921,
        'bedrooms': 3,
        'bathrooms': 1,
        'car_type': 'Cars',
        'park_spots': 2,
        'amenity': ['Wifi'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil6.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'type': 'Villa',
        'price': 820000,
        'address': 'Hayat',
        'area': 4921,
        'bedrooms': 2,
        'bathrooms': 2,
        'car_type': 'Trucks',
        'park_spots': 3,
        'amenity': ['Garden', 'Swimming Pool'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil8.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'type': 'Apartment',
        'price': 420000,
        'address': 'Sarbet',
        'area': 3921,
        'bedrooms': 2,
        'bathrooms': 3,
        'car_type': 'Cars',
        'park_spots': 4,
        'amenity': ['Swimming Pool'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil1.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'type': 'Villa',
        'price': 629000,
        'address': 'Mekhanisa',
        'area': 2921,
        'bedrooms': 1,
        'bathrooms': 1,
        'car_type': 'Vans',
        'park_spots': 1,
        'amenity': ['Gym'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil6.jpg'
      },
      {
        'id': 6,
        'type': 'Apartment',
        'price': 720000,
        'address': 'Bole',
        'area': 1921,
        'bedrooms': 3,
        'bathrooms': 3,
        'car_type': 'Bikes',
        'park_spots': 1,
        'amenity': ['Gym'],
        'homeUrl': '../../assets/ezembil5.jpg'
      }
    ];
this.homesFiltered=this.homes;
  }


    amenityChange(amenity) {
      amenity.value=!amenity.value;
      let filterBy= this.amenities.filter((x)=>x.value==true).map((v)=>{
         return  v.name;
        });

      if(filterBy && filterBy.length){
        this.homesFiltered=this.homes.filter((x)=>x.amenity.some(r=> filterBy.indexOf(r) >= 0))
      }else{
        this.homesFiltered=this.homes;
      }
    }
```

and in the html change the checkbox to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id={{amenity.name}} [checked]="amenity.value" name="amenities" (change)="amenityChange(amenity)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd ditch the pipe approach for that kind of filtering. There's too much code there for simple functionality...

on `amenityChange()`, add some code to filter the home by the selected amenities with true value. Hold the result on the component as `filteredHomes`, and loop through `filteredHomes` instead of `homes`. Remove everything else that is related to the filtering and whatever serves that pipe.

For example;

```
filteredHomes = homes;
.
.
.

amenityChange(item: any, e: any) {
    if (e.srcElement.checked === true) {
      console.log('checked');
      for (let i = 0; i < this.amenities.length; i++) {
        if (this.amenities[i].name === item) {
          this.amenities[i].value = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (e.srcElement.checked === false) {
      console.log('unchecked');
      this.counter = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.amenities.length; i++) {
        if (this.amenities[i].name === item) {
          this.amenities[i].value = false;
        }
      }
    }

    let filteredAmenities = this.amenities.filter(a => a['value'] == true);
    if (filteredAmenities.length == 0){
        this.filteredHomes = homes;
    }
    else{
        this.filteredHomes = [];
        for (let fa of filteredAmenities){
            this.filteredHomes = this.homes.filter(h => h['amenity'].indexOf(fa['name']) > -1)
            .concat(this.filteredHomes);
        }
        //Here you can remove duplicates however you like, here's an example with lodash
        this.filteredHomes = _.uniqBy(this.filteredHomes, 'id');
        }
    }
```

BTW, you would be able to remove the first part of `amenityChange()` if you'll bind each checkbox to a property and use types.

Comment: I opted to bind each checkbox to a property and used types as u suggested and it works just fine.